Dir function in VBA, is there any ways to use logics operator in wildcard?
Sub f()

Dim foldername As String
Dim filename As String
Dim lastrow As Integer

Dim allrange As Range


foldername = "C:\Users\Jay.Xie\Desktop\SW Folder\Data\Data\"

a = "*Group*"


filename = Dir(foldername & a)

I want to search all the files with the word "Group" or "Proportion" in it, is there any ways to achieve that?
I tried using operator in the string itself but it doesn't seem to work.
I can also create the same code again to so that it runs on the word "Proportion" but I don't think its effective.

Yes, Dir supports wildcards, exactly in the way you've shown.

but can it search 2 words at the same time? I want to search "Group" OR "Proportion"

No. You need to loop through all files and check each file name against each string, e.g., by using the Instr function or the Like operator inside an If statement.

Is there any particular reason that you can't run a Dir loop first for "*Group*" and then for "*Proportion*"?  (Optionally, storing the results of each loop in an array or dictionary, and ensuring it is unique, to act on once you have the full list)

You can using the Command-Line DIR
Option Explicit

Sub ListFiles()

    Const PATTERN = "*Group*,*Proportion*"
    Dim FolderName As String
    FolderName = "C:\Users\Jay.Xie\Desktop\SW Folder\Data\Data\"

    Dim wsh As Object, s As String, f, r As Long
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    
    s = wsh.Exec("cmd /c dir /b " & FolderName & PATTERN).StdOut.ReadAll
    For Each f In Split(s, vbCr & vbLf)
        If Len(f) > 0 Then
            r = r + 1
            Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) = f
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox r & " files found", vbInformation

End Sub


Check Whether File Names Contain Any String Using Dir
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Users\Jay.Xie\Desktop\SW Folder\Data\Data\"
    Const FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.xls*" ' adjust!
    ' The following two must be 'in sync'.
    Const COMPARE_STRINGS As String = "Group,Proportion" ' add more
    Const COMPARE_DELIMITER As String = ","
    
    Dim CompareStrings() As String:
    CompareStrings = Split(COMPARE_STRINGS, COMPARE_DELIMITER)
    Dim UpperLimit As Long: UpperLimit = UBound(CompareStrings)
    
    Dim fName As String: fName = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & FILE_PATTERN)
    
    Dim i As Long, BaseName As String, IsMatch As Boolean
    
    Do While Len(fName) > 0
        ' Remove the file extension.
        BaseName = Left(fName, InStrRev(fName, ".") - 1)
        ' Loop through the compare array to determine whether it's a match.
        IsMatch = False
        For i = 0 To UpperLimit
            If InStr(1, BaseName, CompareStrings(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                IsMatch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        
        ' Do something if it's a match, e.g.:
        If IsMatch Then
            Debug.Print fName
        End If
        
        fName = Dir ' next file
    Loop

End Sub

